# Problem with passing iTunes payment method

Tags: itunes

I wanted to use iCloud on my iphone, and therefore created an apple ID, but when I'm trying to sign in to itunes it says since it's my first time using this ID I Should select a payment method, and despite I can see the "none" option in my itunes menu I can't use it. Since I don't have access to either a credit card or iTunes gift card, I was wondering if somebody could tell me if there is another way to pass the payment method.
I have an iPhone 5S with iOS 8.1.3.
Thanks.

Comment: see https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT203905

Answer (score 1):

You can buy a gift card and charge your account with it. Then it won't bother you anymore.